# Do i have to create 2 swap partition if i want to install Ubuntu and Kali in different Hard drive but same Machine

Tags: dual-boot, hard-drive, swap, kali

I have dual boot my laptop with Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 7 in 1TB Hard drive,
apparently my laptop can use another Hard drive and i decided to install Kali 2016.1 for learning purpose in that Hard drive (320GB).
So,The question is,do i have to create swap partition in 320GB Hard drive to install Kali 2016.1 or It just uses the Ubuntu Swap Partition?
which one is safer?please give me advice.
Thanks Before

Comment: Since swap is only used while the OS is booted AFAIK, there shouldn't be a problem sharing a partition. However, it might be better to make a new one since it's on a separate drive.

Answer (score 1):

You can share a swap partition. When Ubuntu is running it will use Swap. When you reboot and pick Kali it will be using the Swap inactive Ubuntu is no longer using. Chances are with 8GB or more of RAM and average work load neither OS will be using Swap.

Note that when if you hibernate your system the Swap partition could be used to hold RAM contents before power is cut to the chips. I believe this shouldn't be a problem because when it wakes from Hibernation it will go to the same OS it hibernated from, or at least I hope it does.